# Detect when object is getting serialized

Tags: java, android

I have a class / object that uses a listener interface. As far as I understand, those can't be serialized, at least I get an NotSerializableException when trying to.

Can I detect from within the object when I's gettings serialized (some form of callback) so I can remove the listener from the object?

I know I can set the listener to null from outside of the object, but it would be easier the way I described.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this. make your class implement `Parcelable` and provide the serialization methods yourself. Then you can decide which members get serialized and how that is done.